# Word Choice: witness versus watch

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

> Skilled sculptors from around the world participate in this month-long event while millions of tourist come to **.........** their incredibly impressive creations.

The optional answers are **watch, look, witness, spectate**. According to the key, the correct answer is *witness* but I feel *watch* is correct.

Which is the correct one and why?

Comment: Are the tourists *looking at* the finished artefacts or *watching/witnessing* them being made?

Comment: What does [CDO](https://www.gotquestions.org/celibacy-priests.html) say about the usage of 'watch'? (They put it under the heading 'grammar' for some reason.)

Comment: watching creations implies that they think they might do something.  “look at” would work fine, but not just plain ‘look’

Answer (score 2):

[Witness](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/witness) has more of the feeling of seeing something of limited duration.

[Watch](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/watch) would fit properly if we were talking about kinetic sculptures, or something which was ongoing, like performance art.

Neither look nor spectate will work in this exact structure. One looks **at** something, and spectate lacks the implication of focus.

You can *spectate* at a sporting event, and *watch* the game, but you will have to be *looking at* the amazing touchdown in order to have **witnessed** it live.

Answer (score 2):

**Witness** implies more thought, and therefore more attention.  Note the English root [**witan**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/witan#Old_English) (*to know*).  It implies both the sensory impression  and understanding of some apparent phenomenon.

**Watch** is more of a duty or chore, which may or may not be successful, (as in "*fell asleep watching TV*"), and may not require full attention, or even the outward senses, ("*I keep a close watch on this heart of mine..."* - J. Cash).

---

None of the suggested words *watch, look, witness, spectate* when put in the defective sample sentence would make it correct English:

> Skilled sculptors from around the world participate in this month-long
>   event while millions of tourist come to ......... their incredibly
>   impressive creations.

One may *witness* an act of creation, or *a* creation, but not a set of objects.  To "*witness their... creations*" would imply the thing being is made is *the sculptors*, as objects of manufacture (i.e. robots or androids) perhaps.

To *watch* implies the watchers might be there to guard the statuary.

Less specific verbs that would fit:  *see*, *view*, or *behold*.

Comment: I think this answer captures the sense that "watch" refers more to the process of observing, during which nothing of note could happen.  "Witness" refers to observing a specific thing of consequence.